# php session to store and show only the last 5 view products

Tags: php, mysql, session, foreach

I want to make a session to store then show the last 5 products see by the user... but is not work properlly

firstly is store the same ID products if i referesh and I want to store only different ID(products)
2. secondly is not showing me more than 1 row(1 query) even if I will have more ID store(different products see by the user like id:3,5,5,6,2) is showing me only the last ID store in this case
2.... i want to show all the queries..

.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
    $_SESSION['lastViewProducts'][] = $id;
    if(count ($_SESSION['lastViewProducts']) > 5 ){
        array_shift($_SESSION['lastViewProducts']);
        }
    foreach( $_SESSION['lastViewProducts'] as $keyLASTview=>$valueLASTview) { 
        $stmtLastVIEW = $con->prepare('SELECT id, product_name, price, details, category, subcategory, size, date_added, image, brand_name, product_color, vizualizari FROM products WHERE id=?');
        $stmtLastVIEW->bind_param('i', $valueLASTview);
        $stmtLastVIEW->execute();
        $stmtLastVIEW->bind_result($idSelectDetalii, $produsNumeDetalii, $priceDetalii, $produsDetalii, $produsCategory, $produsSubcategory, $produsSize,  $produsDate_added, $imageLocationDetalii, $brandProdusSelectat, $produsColor, $produsVizualizari);
        $lastVIEWproduct = '';
        while ($stmtLastVIEW->fetch())    {
            $lastVIEWproduct .='titlu: '.$idSelectDetalii.' <img src="'.$imageLocationDetalii.'" class="img-responsive">';
            }
        $stmtLastVIEW->free_result(); 
    }
}
```

I am really stuck... I cant figure up to fix this problem maybe other variant??
Also 3. thirdly IF the user is on the same page products.php?id=3 and the id=3 it is stored in the session I dont want to show this... `WHERE id=?(for the showing last 5 products views) and  id is not (the $id)?` how to write the mysql select statement and where clause? if i want also a negation

Comment: you need to remove this line `$lastVIEWproduct = '';`

Comment: u need to `$stmtLastVIEW->fetchAll()`instead of `$stmtLastVIEW->fetch()` because `fetch()` give u only 1 result and `fetchAll()` gives u an array with all results.

Comment: now is giving me `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll()`

Comment: Because `mysqli` has no `fetchAll` method, it has `fetch_all`

Comment: and in this case? how i can do that?

Comment: There's already an answer, read it please.

Comment: same error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all() in `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic had some mistakes. You can try with this code :

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 

    //1. Store only differents ids in the session by creating an associative array
    $_SESSION['lastViewProducts'][$id] = $id;

    //3. Don't show the $_GET['id'] in the list
    $ids = array_filter($_SESSION['lastViewProducts'], function($currentID) use($id) {
        return $id != $currentId;
    });


    //Keep only 5 distincts articles
    $ids = array_slice(array_unique($ids), 0, 5);

    //2. declare your string OUTSIDE the foreach
    $lastVIEWproduct = '';
    foreach($ids as  $valueLASTview) { 
        $stmtLastVIEW = $con->prepare('SELECT id, product_name, price, details, category, subcategory, size, date_added, image, brand_name, product_color, vizualizari FROM products WHERE id=?');
        $stmtLastVIEW->bind_param('i', $valueLASTview);
        $stmtLastVIEW->execute();
        $stmtLastVIEW->bind_result($idSelectDetalii, $produsNumeDetalii, $priceDetalii, $produsDetalii, $produsCategory, $produsSubcategory, $produsSize,  $produsDate_added, $imageLocationDetalii, $brandProdusSelectat, $produsColor, $produsVizualizari);
        while ($stmtLastVIEW->fetch())    {
            $lastVIEWproduct .='titlu: '.$idSelectDetalii.' <img src="'.$imageLocationDetalii.'" class="img-responsive">';
        }

        $stmtLastVIEW->free_result(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: is giving me 2 error  a. `Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in line 20 is this (   });  )` b. `arning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in line 28 this (  foreach($ids as  $valueLASTview) {   )  `

Comment: same error ... also it is giving a new error `Notice: Undefined variable: ids`line this (  $ids = array_filter($ids, function($currentID) use($id) {   )`

Comment: it is giving now more rows... then the limit 5, and also this error `Notice: Undefined variable: currentId in line  ( return $id != $currentId;  )`

Comment: Please replace currentID by currentId

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137383/discussion-between-alcatraz007-and-guillaume-stlr).

Comment: It's work thank you for helping me and also to explain me how to fix that